# resolution of linear $\omega$-periodic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the following linear $\omega$-periodic equation :
$$\frac{dw}{dt}=[-V(t)+\frac{F(t)}{\lambda}]w \\\ t \in \mathbb{R} $$
Let $W(t,s,\lambda),t \geq s, s \in \mathbb{R}$ be the evolution operator of th system above.

We have also $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-V(t)y $$ with the evolution operator $Y(t,s)$

We know that $\phi(t):=W(t,0,\lambda_0)\phi_0$  is an $\omega$-periodic solution of the first system.

The thing that i'm tring to figure out is the following result :
" By the constant-variation formula we obtain $\phi(t)=Y(t,\tau)\phi(\tau)+\int_{\tau}^{t} Y(t,s) \frac{F(s)}{\lambda_0} \phi(s) ds$, $\forall t \geq \tau$ "

I have the impression that they used the Cauchy formula for a differential equation with second member however here we have homogeneous equation..

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They computed
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(Y(τ,t)ϕ(t))=Y(τ,t)V(t)ϕ(t)+Y(τ,t)ϕ'(t)=Y(τ,t)\frac{F(t)}{λ}ϕ(t).
$$
After integration this becomes
$$
ϕ(t)=Y(t,τ)ϕ(τ)+\int_τ^tY(t,s)\frac{F(s)}{λ}ϕ(s).
$$
So yes, this indeed applies the solution formula for the inhomogeneous equation
$$
w'(t)+V(t)w(t)=r(t),\text{ where } r(t)=\frac{F(t)}{λ}w(t).
$$